# Converting Month Number into Name

Tags: javascript, date

I need to change the Month Number I retrieved from Database and convert it into the month's name. The Month Number is placed into an array and being a complete newbie to the world of Arrays I am not sure what is the best method to do the replacement.

[image: The array result once retrieved from database]

```
        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var month = [];
        var caseidnum = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            month.push(data[i].Month);
            caseidnum.push (data[i].Num);   
        }
```

Comment: If this is your code, you can easily use: `month.push(monthNames[(int)data[i].Month - 1]);` instead of this line: `month.push(data[i].Month);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `data[i].Month` (-1 if `data[i].Month` goes from 1 to 12) as the index of the `monthNames` array.

Replace this:

```
month.push(data[i].Month);
```

by:

```
month.push(monthNames[data[i].Month - 1]);
```

Comment: It worked thanks but can you explain why the '- 1' is needed ?

Comment: That's because `data[i].Month` returns a number from 1 to 12, but the array of `monthNames` is indexed from 0 to 11. That means if `data[i].Month` is 1 (for January), we need to get the first element of the array (index 0).

Answer (score 1):

The method of creating an array of objects makes the most sense, especially if you think you might need short and long month names:

var monthNames = [ { longName: "January", shortName: "Jan" }, ... , { longName: "December", shortName: "Dec" } ] ;

You would lookup a month as, say, `monthNames[i].longName`, for output purposes.

Otherwise an array of strings would work as well.

Generally, months run from 0 to 11 ... you may need to adjust by one if yours run 1 to 12.

Comment: Ahhh so thats what the '-1' is for ? I will consider doing the shortname, longname seeing as there is more variables I need to include in the graph I am making.

Answer (score 1):

You were correct in writing a for loop to iterate through the objects in the data array, however to get the month's name you can't just index the original data array. The original data array does not contain the month's name. You must index the monthNames array as such:

```
for(var i in data) {
     month.push(monthNames[data[i].Month - 1]); 
}
```

An alternative solution using the array method [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) functions is a bit more concise.

```
data.map((x) => month.push(monthNames[x.Month - 1]));
```